# Intervention Image 2.3, resize, fill background, vertical and horizontal align a image

Tags: php, image, laravel, intervention

I'm using Intervention Image with Laravel. Im running into a issue that i want to manipulate a earlier saved image. First i check if the image exists, if so, then i want to resize it to a width of 181px and height of 80px. After resizing i want to vertical and horizontal align the image and fill the background with a white color. I don't want to lose any quality of the picture. Can someone explain me how to do it?

Comment: Hi there.  Can you please show us the code for what you've done so far?

Comment: You say you want to horizontally and vertically align the image - align with what? With another image? How can it not be aligned if you have forced all your images to the same size?

Comment: Currently i don't have any code. Im still thinking how to do it.

@MarkSetchell, i want to resize the image and keep the quality. Lets imagine that we have a image (i.e. http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/philips_2013_logo.png and pick the left one). Normally it would be a logo without any white space around it. Now im going to create a new image and paste this logo into the image. The image is 100x100 and the new image 200x200, so i want that image aligned in the middle of the square